# Azure DB connection string is null with an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy an app made with ASP.NET Core on Azure. So the first thing I did was a creating a server and a DB in Azure. Then, I added in my *secrets.json* file the connection string given by Azure along with my local DB connection string :

```
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HikingContext": "Server=******\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=***;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "HikingContextProd": "Data Source=****.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=***;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

  }
```

When I run my application locally in a production environment to check if the azure db connection works, I get the following error

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name
```

The error happens in the *startup.cs* file

```
  if(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
                services.AddDbContext<HikingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HikingContextProd")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

It seems that the startup file doesn't find the Azure db server despite the fact that I can actually connect to the server through SSMS with the id and the password. I checked the connection string multiple times and I don't see any mistakes so I don't really understand why it's not working ?

Here's the full error message :

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
  Arborescence des appels de procédure :
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at Hiking.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\*****\Desktop\BeCode - Personnel\.NET\Hiking\Hiking\Startup.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
```

Comment: I think the princess you seek is in another castle... How did the app get onto azure? What process did you follow to deploy it?

Comment: @CaiusJard I haven't deployed it yet. I just a created a sql server db online with azure and I wanted to try if my local app could connect to the online db and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see.. so, if you put a breakpoint on that line `if` what actually is the value of the environment variable? Is the connection string getting set to azure properly? Is your ip address added in azure db server firewall? Does `Configuration.GetConnectionString("HikingContextProd")` return the expected string (paste it into the immediate window)?

Comment: @CaiusJard The value of the environment variable is Production. The connection string is correct and there are no firewall issues but indeed the Configuration.GetConnectionString("HikingContextProd") is null. I'm going to update the question and post the full error message given by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

After a day spent on this issue, I finally found the origin of the problem. It seems that if you're in a production environnement and you want to connect a local ASP.NET Core app to an Azure sql server, it won't work if the connection string is in the *secrets.json* file.

So instead of putting your Azure connection string in the *secrets.json* file, use the *Key Vault* provided by Azure to store your connection string. I did it and now I can successfully connect my local ASP.NET Core app to an Azure sql server.